# Web Grid with dynamically created model in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am builing an ASP.Net mvc3 website which comprises of a series of forms all built on top of different models. Once the user fills up each form a "Confirm" page is shown which will show the fields of the form filled along with data in grid format to the user. I am facing difficulty in showing the Confirm view as the model keeps on changing for each form.
Following is my Controller method for Confirm:

```
public ActionResult Confirm(string ReqType)
        {
            var result = new List<dynamic>();
            if (ReqType == "AcctDesc")
            {
                DbContext.AcctDescDbContext objAcctDescDbContext = new DbContext.AcctDescDbContext();
                Models.AccountDesc objAcctDesc = objAcctDescDbContext.GetLatestRecord();
                ViewData["AcctDesc"] = objAcctDesc;
                ViewBag.ObjectModel = objAcctDesc;


                    var obj = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();

                    obj.Add("Req_Name",objAcctDesc.Req_Name);
                    obj.Add("Req_Date",objAcctDesc.Req_Date);
                    obj.Add("ApprovalGroup",objAcctDesc.ApprovalGroup);
                    obj.Add("Account",objAcctDesc.AC_proposed);
                    obj.Add("Reason",objAcctDesc.AC_definition);
                    obj.Add("Language",objAcctDesc.AC_language);
                    obj.Add("CurrentShortText", objAcctDesc.AC_Currentshorttext);
                    obj.Add("CurrentLongText", objAcctDesc.AC_CurrentLongtext);
                    obj.Add("NewShortText", objAcctDesc.AC_Newshorttext);
                    obj.Add("NewLongText", objAcctDesc.AC_Newlongtext);

                    result.Add(obj);
                }
            ViewBag.result = result;
            return View();

            }
```

Following is the Confirm view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Confirm";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMasterDataForms.cshtml";
}

<div>

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.result);  

    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    <div id="grid"> 
        @grid.GetHtml() 
    </div> 
}
</div>
```

The problem is the gird is not getting rendered in the Confirm page-blank Html is coming up, what is the issue here? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I did a strip down version of your code to generate a `WebGrid` and it is working fine as far as I can see. Here is the output and my code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zq0lHy. Also I would recommend using a typed `List` rather than using `dynamic` in this case and same for `ViewData` or `ViewBag`.